# Can't get custom metrics data when using OpenCensus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, opencensus

I am following this guide [monitoring_opencensus_metrics_quickstart-go](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census?hl=zh-cn#monitoring_opencensus_metrics_quickstart-go). Besides, I also tried the way from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947466/6463558).

Code here:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"

    "contrib.go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver"
    "go.opencensus.io/stats"
    "go.opencensus.io/stats/view"
    "golang.org/x/exp/rand"
)

var (
    // The task latency in milliseconds.
    latencyMs = stats.Float64("task_latency", "The task latency in milliseconds", "ms")
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    v := &view.View{
        Name:        "task_latency_distribution",
        Measure:     latencyMs,
        Description: "The distribution of the task latencies",
        Aggregation: view.Distribution(0, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000, 4000),
    }
    if err := view.Register(v); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to register the view: %v", err)
    }

    exporter, err := stackdriver.NewExporter(stackdriver.Options{
        ProjectID: os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"),
        MonitoringClientOptions: []option.ClientOption{
            option.WithCredentialsFile(path.Join("./.gcp/stackdriver-monitor-admin.json")),
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    view.RegisterExporter(exporter)
    view.SetReportingPeriod(60 * time.Second)
    // Flush must be called before main() exits to ensure metrics are recorded.
    defer exporter.Flush()

    if err := exporter.StartMetricsExporter(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting metric exporter: %v", err)
    }
    defer exporter.StopMetricsExporter()

    // Record 100 fake latency values between 0 and 5 seconds.
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        ms := float64(5*time.Second/time.Millisecond) * rand.Float64()
        fmt.Printf("Latency %d: %f\n", i, ms)
        stats.Record(ctx, latencyMs.M(ms))
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done recording metrics")
}
```

I run above code locally, NOT in GCE, GAE and GKE environments.

At the metrics explorer web UI, here is the metric query condition:

- Resource Type: `Consumed API`
- Metric: `custom.googleapis.com/opencensus/task_latency_distribution`

Full query:

```
fetch consumed_api
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/opencensus/task_latency_distribution'
| align delta(1m)
| every 1m
| group_by [],
    [value_task_latency_distribution_aggregate:
       aggregate(value.task_latency_distribution)]
```

The service account has `Monitoring Admin` role.

But got `No data is available for the selected time frame`.

[image]

Comment: Did you double verify that all of these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census#prereqs) have been taken care of?

Comment: @AartiS Of course. opencensus and cloud trace service work fine, but cloud monitoring does not work, as described in the question

Comment: I think for this kind of behavior , it is better to open a support case with Google (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs)  then it will be easy to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me but I've tended to do things slightly differently:

- `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/creds` instead of `MonitoringClientOptions{}`;
- <strike>Previously (!?) I had problems with distributions with a 0 bucket; try removing that initial (0) bucket and try again;</strike>
- Drop the `resource.type` from the metrics explorer; from APIs Explorer, if any, this should be `global`

Google APIs Explorer is an excellent way to diagnose Stackdriver API challenges. You can use it to list metrics and to list timeseries (replace `your-project-id` and update the 2 `interval` values):

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.metricDescriptors/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Fyour-project-id%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22metric.type%3D%5C%22custom.googleapis.com%2Fopencensus%2Ftask_latency_distribution%5C%22%22%7D

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Fyour-project-id%22%2C%22aggregation.alignmentPeriod%22%3A%22%2B300s%22%2C%22aggregation.crossSeriesReducer%22%3A%22REDUCE_MEAN%22%2C%22aggregation.perSeriesAligner%22%3A%22ALIGN_DELTA%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22metric.type%3D%5C%22custom.googleapis.com%2Fopencensus%2Ftask_latency_distribution%5C%22%22%2C%22interval.endTime%22%3A%222020-09-08T23%3A59%3A59Z%22%2C%22interval.startTime%22%3A%222020-09-08T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%7D

Using Chrome's Developer Console, you can find one of Stackdriver's calls to the API to more easily reproduce it, e.g.

```
filter: metric.type="custom.googleapis.com/opencensus/task_latency_distribution"
aggregation.crossSeriesReducer: REDUCE_MEAN
aggregation.alignmentPeriod: +60s
aggregation.perSeriesAligner: ALIGN_DELTA
secondaryAggregation.crossSeriesReducer: REDUCE_NONE
interval.startTime: 2020-09-08T23:59:59Z
interval.endTime: 2020-09-08T00:00:00Z
```